# How to connect multiple Virtual machines to SFTP using Key based authentication towards a remote machine

Tags: ssh, rsa, vmware

I have set of Virtual Machines (VMWare) and I want to connect to remote SFTP server using public-private key based authentication. Initial transfer of public keys from each of the VMs to remote SFTP server and further connection works fine. But when I create a batch of 20 virtual machines, it is tedious to copy from each of those and transfer to remote host.

And, the upgrades causes the automation to fail as the new VM has newer set of keys. Is there a way to use common pair of keys in a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would create a master VM and copy all the keys into it. Then you can clone it to new VMs. This way you have new VMs with keys already in.